# How do I know if a class can go above rank 10?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Throughout the story, I found a quest that unlocked Medic Gunner's ability to go beyond rank 10. However, there is no marking in the UI for classes that can go above rank 10. There is an obnoxious warning when you have a class that's currently maxed out, telling you to go play something else, but that doesn't seem to show up on any of my rank 10 classes that I unlocked - only the base 6 classes.

Now, I would expect this message to be an indicator, even if a poor one, but I don't seem to get CP on classes that it doesn't warn me about either. So currently I have no idea if there's a simple indicator that tells me what classes can go to rank 20. Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell:

- For the base 6 characters, you can look for "Side Story" quest completions.
- For any other character, you can check their rank in the hero menu. If the rank is 20 (as opposed to 10), you can take the class to rank 20.

There are no other visual indicators, and unfortunately this is probably the easiest way to tell. At least, there's an easy *enough* solution by looking at the hero menu, so you don't have to go through the quest menu to try to guess at what quest improves who.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to find if your character (that is currently level 10) can currently upgrade to level 20, I just found probably the probably easiest and quickest solution.

In the class selection, use Y to use nopon coin/doublon. If your character can go to level 11 (and beyoooond !) you will get a selection menu. If you still can't, you'll get a message telling you this character can't increase level.

Here is a class I can increase : [image]

And here is one I can't yet : [image]

And as a bonus. If like me you have so many of those nopon coins they waste in auto-sell, It could make sense to buy a few relevant level 11 so you will have a visual cue of what classe can goes to level 20.

Comment: Actually just came back to this question after finding this same solution. It is not *perfect*, as you still have to click through the whole class selection to see if you can use Nopon silver coins on all your level 10 classes to see if you get an error vs. coin usage screen... but without some other visual indicator, which isn't there, this is definitely the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

On the class selection screen, you can open the class informations with the ZR button. If you look it up, you can see that every class unlock a master art at rank 20 (the class' master art). So I assume every class can reach rank 20.

Comment: This is not what I mean - classes are by default capped at rank 10. How do I know if I can exceed that cap and go to 20?

Comment: I understood the question to be if a class can unlock the rank cap, but it's about to see if a class has already unlocked the rank cap, is that right ? In this case, short of remembering it or doing a battle and see if a class get some exp, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that you're talking about the character's Ascension Quest? If so, there is a thing on page 1 of each person's hero profile in the Hero Roster menu that tells you about it.

[image: incomplete ascension quest]
[image: complete ascension quest]

I am assuming that this being marked as "completed" means you've unlocked its level 20 capabilities.

However, **be cautious**, as the silhouettes of non-unlocked people in the Hero Roster menu can spoil you.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble finding this "hero profile" in the hero list screen. Can you provide a screenshot or walkthrough of how to get to it? I might not have unlocked this feature yet, also. I'm only asking this because I've started to unlock side story quests for the main party so if this feature does become apparent later that will be wholly welcome.

Comment: Uhm I don't actually have the game so I don't know. [sheepish look] I assumed it'd be unlocked when you get the first hero so it might just be hidden in some other menu.

Comment: @Seiyria : it's in the system submenu. In the french version it's only called 'heros' (exactly like the heros in the main menu, so there can be a lot of confusion).